# Finding a namespace from lein repl

Tags: web-applications, clojure, clojurescript, pedestal

EDIT : SOLVED
My issue was coming from two things -- I had a syntax error in the defmacro somewhere. I deleted it and wrote a small function that I could then access (only after restarting the repl). The big second-issue was that I was ignorant to the fact repl needed to be restarted to recognize any changes I had made. Would never have figured this out without the concrete answer given below =).

I have been working through the pedestal tutorial on github, and it recommends testing some things via repl - my problem is that I can't find the namespace/ macros or functions I am interested in working with.

```
user=> (require '(junkyard-client.html-templates))
nil
user=> (def t (junkyard-client-templates))

user=> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: 
  junkyard-client-templates in this context, compiling:
  (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init3290053673397861360.clj:1:8)
```

I have tried other things syntactically, such as (require 'junkyard-client.html-templates).
This is at v2.0.10 in the pedestal tutorial:https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial/wiki/Slicing-Templates

EDIT: this is what I am trying to get to

```
(ns junkyard-client.html-templates
  (:use [io.pedestal.app.templates :only [tfn dtfn tnodes]]))

(defmacro junkyard-client-templates
  []
  {:junkyard-client-page (dtfn (tnodes "junkyard-client.html" "hello") #{:id})
   :other-counter (dtfn (tnodes "tutorial-client.html" "other-counter") #{:id}
  })
```

problem stage
https://github.com/Sammons/clojure-projects/tree/d9e0b4f6063006359bf34a419deb31a879c7a211/pedestal-app-tutorial/junkyard-client

solved stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`require`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/require) makes the namespace available within your current namespace, but does not make the symbols directly available. You still need to namespace qualify the symbols, unless you  use `:refer` or [`use`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/use).

```
(require '[junkyard-client.html-templates])

(def t (junkyard-client.html-templates/junkyard-client-templates))
```

It might be preferable to alias the namespace or refer the specific symbol you are using, for convenience.

**Alias:**

```
(require '[junkyard-client.html-templates :as templates])

(def t (templates/junkyard-client-templates))
```

**Refer:**

```
(require '[junkyard-client.html-templates :refer [junkyard-client-templates]])

(def t (junkyard-client-templates))
```

**Note:** `require` and `:refer` is generally preferred over `use`.

Comment: The namespace is still unfound?

user=> (require '[junkyard-client.html-templates :as templates])
user=> Exception namespace 'junkyard-client.html-templates' not found  clojure.core/load-lib (core.clj:5380)

I must be doing something wierd. I am starting the repl from the root directory (of junkyard client) and I can successfully (start) without issues. Thank you for this answer though as it helps me see  more clearly how things should work.

Comment: Try running `lein repl` from within the directory with the `project.clj` file, so it picks up your dependencies and configuration.

Comment: That's where I run from, it hooks into the project and loads up the dependencies

Comment: I can also hook into a different namespace without any problem - that one lives in a different file, but in the same directory as the namespace I am stuck on. I will figure it out eventually and bring back whatever is tripping me.

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the [`html_templates.clj`](https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial/blob/v2.0.10/tutorial-client/app/src/tutorial_client/html_templates.clj) file?

Comment: yes, same folder as start.clj, rendering.clj, post-processing.clj, behavior.clj (and simulated folder)

Comment: +1 for the concrete answer, never would have figured it out without it. And for helping a noob (thanks)